# MOD operator in Teradata SQL Assistent 15

Tags: sql, teradata, modulo

can't understand why my old sripts didn't work. Problem in MOD operator.

SELECT MOD(20,2)

Error:
Query failed. 3706: Syntax error ...

Can't understand why MOD operator doesnt work any more.

Teradata SQL Assistent 15.10

Comment: Show us a complete query that fails. (As minimal as possible.)

Comment: for example: 
SELECT MOD(-25,7)

can be problem in 15 version? before i had 13 or 14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MOD(-25,7)` is/was ODBC syntax which was (sometimes) automatically translated by the ODBC driver. Newer ODBC versions don't support it anymore (it was deprecated years ago). You either connect now using .NET or a newer ODBC driver.

The correct Teradata syntax  is `-25 MOD 7`.